# Ошибка при работе с массивами

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int i;
    float ost, a[6], b[6];

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("A[%i] = ", a[i]);
        scanf("%f", a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        ost = a[i] % 2;
        if (ost == 1) {
            b[i] = ln(i + 1.5) * -1;
        } else {
            b[i] = ln(i + 1.5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но все равно неправильно работает (sizeof(a) пока не использовал), программа выводит A[0] = везде! И сортирует неправильно.

Comment: Задание хотя бы озвучили.

Answer (score 3):

При индексации массивов лучше использовать оператор sizeof:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
}
```

При вызове функции scanf нужно передавать адрес переменной, в которую нужно писать:

```
scanf("%f", &a[i]);
```

Оператор взятия модуля % применяется к целым числам:

```
ost = (int)a[i] % 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Я телепат!
Все 7 заменить на 6!
И выкинуть код. :)

Comment: Спасибо, а в строке ost = a[i] % 2; ???

Comment: В строке ost = a[i] % 2; нужно поменять тип операндов. Например, так: ost = (int)a[i] % 2;

Comment: Если хочется вывести: A[0] =, A[1] =, то делайте так: printf("A[%i] = ", i);